# Integrate a newsletter on a customerziable registration form as well as sidebar in wordpress without registration

Tags: wordpress

I have recently started using wordpress and have no much knowledge about the plugins which are used . I am currently in a situation where i need to make a customerizable registration form with a checkbox saying whether the user wants to  subscribe for a newsletter or not . Also the user must be able to subscribe to the newsletter without registering.

I am able to make a newsletters without registering and send newsletters to those users who have subscribed for newsletters using Email newsletter plugin .

Another plugin which i have come across is News-letter sign up , where am not sure whether the registration form is customerizable as well as unable to understand where the action must be directed to ... its too complicated for me to understand.

Also when the admin logs in he must be able to send at a time newsletters to subscribed  newsletter users as well as registerd users who have checked the newsletter checkbox.

I have searched for making registration form customerizable but still in a confusion how to send  at a time newsletters to subscribed  newsletter users as well as registerd users who have checked the newsletter checkbox .

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Gravity Forms - http://www.gravityforms.com/

I'll be renewing my developer licence for that this month, it is a massive timesaver if you are getting involved in Wordpress - if you have ever used Wufoo, it's just like that.  Handles simple forms to very advanced complicated ones with calculations and conditional logic. Depending on the licence you get you can integrate MailChimp and Campaign Monitor into your forms (you haven't said how you are handling the newsletters and subscriptions).

If you want there are also two good free plugins which are kind of endorsed by Mailchimp and Campaign Monitor and will add a sign up widget;

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp-widget/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-campaign-monitor-forms/